# TP-LINK TL-WN722N weird behavior

Tags: networking, arch-linux, wifi

I tried using the TP-LINK TL-WN722N wifi adapter with my fresh Arch Linux installation, but it has a really weird behavior. In my house, I have 2 access point, from which one is easily accessible from my room and the other hardly accessible.
For some reason the adapter seems to show only the one which is hardly accessible. Furthermore, wicd doesn't seem to pay any attention to the adapter, and I have no idea how to make it use the adapter.

When I use airodump-ng, I see the closer AP with power `-1` and ESSID `<length: 0>` which is really weird. This doesn't happen on my other computers, from which one is also running Arch Linux.

Another extremely annoying thing is that I can't use aireplay-ng, since I receive only about 0-2 ACK responses and the attack does nothing.

I've looked in the logs, and again, there is some weird information about the adapter. Whenever I use `iwconfig`, this error is added to the log:

```
ERROR: @wl_dev_intvar_get: error (-1)
ERROR: @wl_cfg80211_get_tx_power: error (-1)
```

When I set the adapter's state to `up`, I get this error:

```
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp0s20u1: link is not ready
```

Neverthless the internet connection seems to work fine with the hardly accessible AP, and drivers (ath9k_htc) are already installed.

Anyone's got any idea why this happens and how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Is the SSID of the closer AP hidden?

Comment: @RuiFRiberio No, it's not supposed to be and it's not seen as hidden by any other PC/adapter

Comment: Anything on channels 12-14?

Comment: @RuiFRiberio The closer AP is on channel 13

Comment: A US adapter wont work on channel 13-15...FCC rules. If outside US, define in the wifi configurations the country, you might be lucky. If in US, change it to a channel bellow 12. My wifi has an American Sony notebook, and I had the same problem, till I have her a 5GHz wifi adapter.

Comment: @RuiFRiberio I don't live in the US, how do I do change the country in wifi configurations? Is it in the router or on the computer?

Comment: What is your country?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39616/discussion-between-matthew-and-rui-f-ribeiro).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your computer is not seeing the nearest wifi AP as it is in channel 13, which by definition *should* not be used in the US.

I advise you to try and configure wpa_supplicant for your country code.

In `wpa_supplicant.conf` please add the directive:

```
country=CZ
```

Then disable and enable wifi again. Hopefully if the card has not any other limitation, you might see now your nearest AP.

If it works, you might want also to change the country code in the AP. As a curious note, changing the country code for a non-US country, will allow you to increase a little more the potency. At least, it does in my TPLINK model.

If it does not work, the limitation may be on the firmware side, try changing the channel on the AP to a channel bellow 12

Comment: This didn't help, I'm still not able to see the AP with neither wifi-menu or airodump-ng

Comment: the hw itself acn be limited, change the ap to a channel bellow 12

Comment: Alright, just tried aireplay-ng on an AP with channel 1 and it worked, I guess it's a hardware issue. But one thing is still puzzling me. The adapter works fine on Windows

Comment: After a bit of searching I found out that you need to change the regulatory domain of your system. You can do this with crda. Thank you for giving me a good starting point.